# BIND reverse lookup not working

Tags: dns, bind

I've configured my bind server successfully for DNS lookup. However, the reverse lookup (IP Address to hostname) is not working.

Here's my zone file:

```
$TTL                            38400
@               IN     SOA      brave-vesperia.com. email.com (
                                1500723860;
                                10800;
                                3600;
                                604800;
                                38400);

                                IN      NS      brave-vesperia.com.
                                IN      NS      bind-9.brave-vesperia.com.

76.50                           IN      PTR     nagios.brave-vesperia.com.
76.60                           IN      PTR     win2016.brave-vesperia.com.
```

Running dig on any of these addresses returns `NXDOMAIN`. There are no error messages in my bind log as far as I can see and as I mentioned, normal lookup works fine.

Here's the relevant part of my log when I start BIND:

```
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.020 not using config file logging statement for logging due to -g option
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.021 managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 0
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.021 zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.022 zone 192.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1500723860
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.023 zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.025 zone brave-vesperia.com/IN: loaded serial 1486898743
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.025 zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.026 zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.026 all zones loaded
13-Nov-2020 20:59:35.027 running
```

Comment: Are you using `dig -x` for reverse lookup? Otherwise you have to use this notation: `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa PTR`

Comment: @Virsacer Thank you so much. I feel a bit stupid now.